# Lost SQL 2014 installation media and needing to install on new server

Tags: sql-server-2014, installation

We have an on-site installation of SQL 2014 that we want to move to a new server. We are no longer engaged with the company that did the original installation.  We can not find any media/installation files and the description we have of our license (within our internal documentation) is:

Microsoft SQL Server Per Core 2014, along with a License Key and a note about security access as "All users with access to "Company Name".

We have searched for the installation files on the server with no success. Is there going to be any way for us to get our SQL installed onto a new server without having to purchase a new license?